# Overloaded stream insertion operator (<<) in the sub-class

Tags: c++

I have a  class A, for which I have defined an (overloaded) stream insertion operator. I publicly derive a class B from this class A, which has an additional data member. Therefore I'll need to redefine the overloaded stream insertion operator for the derived class and I've do it this way:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
    int i;
    char c;
public:
    A(int i = 0, char c = ' ') {
        this->i = i;
        this->c = c;
    }
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const A&);
};

class B : public A {
    double d;
public:
    B(int i = 0, char c = ' ', double d = 0.0) : A(i, c), d(d) {}
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const B&);
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const A& a) {
    out << "\nInteger: " << a.i << "\nCharacter: " << a.c << endl;
    return out;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const B& b) {
    out << b;
    out << "\nDouble: " << b.d << endl;
    return out;
}

int main() {
    A a(10, 'x');
    B b(20, 'y', 5.23);
    cout << b;

    return 0;
}
```

> **Question-1:** Is this an appropriate technique of doing so? If not, kindly let me know where I'm going wrong.
>
> **Question-2:** On running, this program crashes. Why so?

Answer (score 3):

One common way to support this is to have the overloaded operator invoke a virtual member function:

```
class A { 
public:
    virtual std::ostream &write(std::ostream &os) const { 
        // write self to os
        os << "A\n";
        return os;
    }
};

class B : public A { 
public:
    virtual std::ostream &write(std::ostream &os) const { 
        // write self to os
        // This can use the base class writer like:
        A::write(os);
        os << "B\n";
        return os;
    }
};
```

Then the operator overload just invokes that member function:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, A const &a) {
    return a.write(os);
}
```

Since `write` is virtual and you're passing the `A` by (const) reference, this invokes the correct member function based on the actual type (i.e., `A::write` if the object is really an instance of `A`, and `B::write` if it's an instance of `B`).

For example, we could exercise these something like this:

```
int main() { 
    A a;
    B b;

    std::cout << a << "\n";
    std::cout << b << "\n";
}
```

...which produces output like this:

```
A

A
B
```

In real use, you probably want to make the `write` functions protected, and make the `operator<<` a friend of `A`.

Comment: How can I call A's version of the stream insertion operator within B's version of the stream insertion operator function?

Comment: Why must `operator<<` be a friend of `A`? (I confess to a personal dislike of `friend`-- I avoid it when I can.)

Comment: @Beta: it doesn't *have* to be a friend of `A`, but you get better encapsulation by making it a friend (i.e., with it as a friend, you can make `write` protected, so the rest of the world doesn't see it).

Comment: I was told that the stream operators can only be overloaded as friend functions...oh man, I'm so confused right now. !!! :(

Comment: @User2k14: a common confusion. They don't have to be friends. They [should normally be free functions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29885358/179910), but they only have to be `friend`s if they need access to part of the object that's not public (but they do usually need that, so `friend` is common for them).

Comment: Hmm... I wouldn't call that better *encapsulation*, since `write` does exactly the same thing as `<<` (which is just syntactic sugar for `write`), but I'll concede that it's a better *interface* in that it has one fewer public method.

Comment: Smart solution BTW. :)

Answer (score 0):

The program crashes because your second insertion operator calls itself:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const B& b) {
  out << b;  // <--YIKES!
  out << "\nDouble: " << b.d << endl;
  return out;
}
```

Generally this is a good approach, although I prefer to give the classes a public virtual `print(ostream&) const` function, and have the insertion operator call that.

Comment: My bad. I was trying to make use of the fact that the overloaded operator has already been defined for the super class.

Comment: It only prints out the double values now. How do I make it print the int and char values of the superclass too without having to hardcode it?

Comment: @User2k14: Are you sure you want those members to be private?

Comment: How can I call A's version of the stream insertion operator within B's version of the stream insertion operator function?

Comment: Yes, that's the principle of object oriented programming.

Comment: I'm not sure how to invoke the A version of `<<` from within the B version. I can do it in my preferred method (one `operator<<`, `A::print(...)` and `B::print(...)`) if you'd like to see that. (Also, I'd say that polymorphism is *the* principle of OO, while encapsulation is just a good feature of C++.)