# Upcasting and Overloading Stream Operator

Tags: c++

As you can see, only the overloaded version of the stream insertion operator for the base class is called on both instances. I understand why it's so. It's because there is no dynamic binding. But, how do I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
    int i;
    char c;
public:
    A(int i = 0, char c = ' ') {
        this->i = i;
        this->c = c;
    }
    int getI() { return i; }
    char getC() { return c; }
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, A&);
};

class B : public A {
    double d;
public:
    B(int i = 0, char c = ' ', double d = 0.0) : A(i, c), d(d) {}
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, B&);
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& out, A& a) {
    out << "\nInteger: " << a.i << "\nCharacter: " << a.c << endl;
    return out;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& out, B& b) {
    out << "\nInteger: " << b.getI() << "\nCharacter: " << b.getC() << "\nDouble: " << b.d << endl;
    return out;
}

int main() {
    A* a = new A (10, 'x');
    B* b = new B(20, 'y', 5.23);
    A* array[] = { a, b };
    cout << *(array[0]);
    cout << "\n______________________________\n";
    cout << *(array[1]);
    delete a;
    delete b;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

How can I make `cout << *(array[1]);` call the overloaded stream insertion operator that takes an object of B as one of it's arguments?

Comment: Read this: ["What is object slicing?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). Then look how you're `A` array suffers from the what is described in the question and answers.

Comment: @WhozCraig There won't be slicing, the objects are being passed by reference.

Comment: @Phantom look at the declaration `array`. You can't have arrays of native references. It is a flat-out array of `A` only. The initializer using `b` (`array[1]`) is sliced.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oops, was looking at the `operator <<` overloads.

Comment: @Phantom yeah, and looking closer, that array does *nothing* but introduce problems via slicing. It serves no useful purpose at all. The OP could have just sent `a` and `b` to fire the operators.

Comment: [Very related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885223/overloading-the-stream-insertion-operator-for-a-class).

Comment: Thanks for fixing the slicing problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can define virtual member helper functions.

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void toStream(ostream& out) const {
        out << "\nInteger: " << i << "\nCharacter: " << c << endl;
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void toStream(ostream& out) const {
        out << "\nInteger: " << getI() << "\nCharacter: " << getC() << "\nDouble: " << d << endl;
    }
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const A& a) {
    a.toStream(out);
    return out;
}
```

You don't even need 2 `operator<<()`'s anymore.

For `operator >> (istream& in, A& a)`, similar tricks could be done.

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void fromStream(istream& in) {
        // Fill data members with in
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void fromStream(istream& in) {
        // Fill data members with in
    }
};

istream& operator >> (istream& in, A& a) {
    a.fromStream(in);
    return in;
}
```

Comment: What is the solution as a friend function?

Comment: If you insist in not adding virtual member functions, then you could declare destructors as virtual, and use `dynamic_cast` to check if the `A&` passed in was indeed `B&`.

Comment: Oh...that look a bit clumsy. Just for the sake of completeness, can you show how to apply the previous solution that you posted to the stream extraction (>>) operator?

Comment: May be you can define a function called `fromStream` this time. :)

Comment: @User2k14 done. Basically the same with some modifications in constness of parameters.

Comment: Thanks man. Love you. BTW, the input stream operator doesn't work for std::string objects. :/

Comment: It says: `error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

Comment: @User2k14 Sounds strange. You may create another question for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If `A` knows it will be inherited from, you can use Non Virtual Interface: make the operators friend, and write a **protected** (it's not part of the class interface) virtual function that performs the write.