# How to std::cout << a type which has many (ambiguous) user-defined conversion functions?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion, overload-resolution

Here I've got a class in `c++` that deals with large numbers way beyond `long long`. It stores its data as `std::string`. Now I have many, many converters here:

```
class BigInt {
private:
    std::string x;
public:
    operator std::string()        { return x;              }
    operator int()                { return std::stoi(x);   }
    operator long long()          { return std::stoll(x);  }
    operator unsigned long long() { return std::stoull(x); }
    operator double()             { return std::stod(x);   }
    operator long double()        { return std::stold(x);  }
    ...
    BigInt(std::string a) : x(a) {}
    BigInt(long long a) : x(to_string(a)) {}
    ...
}
int main() {
    BigInt x = 10485761048576;
    std::cout << x << std::endl; // Error!
}
```

But what happens is that I get an error:

> More than one operator matches these operands.

That basically means that the function `std::cout` doesn't know which converter to choose. So is there a thing as a "default" converter that choose one of the converters as default when accessing functions?

If there is no that kind of thing, then I guess I would have to call something like `std::cout << (std::string)x << std::endl;` every single time I want to pass the parameter into some kind of overloaded function.

Comment: why don't you overload the stream operator?

Comment: Dupe [Overloading the stream insertion (<<) operator for a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885223/overloading-the-stream-insertion-operator-for-a-class?noredirect=1&lq=1). This is explained in any beginner [c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Reopened this in case there are other viable solutions.

Comment: Implicit conversions to integer values defeat purpose of class . You have to make them `explicit`

Comment: A generic "number" type is a rather bad idea. Do you want integers or reals? They are fundamentally different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply an overload of [`std::ostream` `operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) for your `BigInt`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BigInt& obj)
{
    os << static_cast<std::string>(obj);
    return os;
}
```

In order to be able to use your conversion operators for `const` objects (as required for the above `operator<<`, and it is good practice anyway), you also need to **mark them `const`**, e.g.:

```
//  -----------------------vvvvv--------------
    operator std::string() const { return x; }
```

Now you can use:

```
int main() 
{
    BigInt x = 10485761048576;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
10485761048576
```

[Live demo - Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rsK78vsdT).

Comment: Wait it doesn't really work... In my compiler (MSVC) it tells me that in the linking process: operator<< already defined in BigNumbers.cpp, one or more multiply defined symbols found. I think it is because I already created converters from BigInt to int and long long and stuffs?

Comment: If you define `operator<<` in a header file, then either make it `inline` (`inline std::ostream& operator<< ...`) or put only a declaration in the header (`std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BigInt& obj);`), and the implementation in a cpp file.

Comment: Thanks, that did solve the problem: marking it as inline. It's actually one of the easiest ways isn't it

Comment: That's simply because your converters are implicit... they have priority over the non-member operator

Comment: You can simplify the `operator<<` to a one-liner: `return os << static_cast<std::string>(obj)`.

Comment: @JanSchultke thanks, however I don't see how making it a one liner improve the code in this case (readabilty-wise). But I like the usage of `static_cast` which is better than the C style cast I used earlier. Updated my answer.